# jquery - reveal two different <a> title attr when hovered over one

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have two ( title attr) text boxes shown when I hover over either of these images. Copied this tutorial that works for one, but can't seem to get it to work to reveal both titles simultaneously. Please help! As you can see I'm a rookie

HTML

```
<a href="#" title="This text 2" class="masterTooltip1"><img src="image2.png" /></a>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Tooltip only Text
    $('.masterTooltip,.masterTooltip1').hover(function(){
        // Hover over code
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
    $('<p class="tooltip"></p>')
    .text(title)
    .appendTo('body')
    .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
    // Hover out code
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
    $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(e) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
    $('.tooltip')
    .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
});
});
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
display:none;
position:absolute;
border:1px solid #333;
background-color:#161616;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px;
color:#fff;
font-size:12px Arial;
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to get to? please edit this fiddle and post the new url: http://jsfiddle.net/GMaYu/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GMaYu/

When I hover over either image, I would like to reveal a text box for both images.

Comment: when you edit the fiddle, click on update - that gives a new URL, share that URL.. This would link back to my version.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GMaYu/1/

Sorry about that

Comment: If you are using jqueryUI too you should use `position()` instead of `css()` for the collision detection ala `$('.tooltip').position({ my: "left+20 top+10", of: e, collision: "fit" })`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/GMaYu/4/)**

```
// Tooltip only Text
var toolTip = $('.masterTooltip, .masterTooltip1');
$('.masterTooltip, .masterTooltip1').hover(function () {
    // Hover over code
    $.each(toolTip, function () {
        var title = $(this).attr('title');
        var classTooltip = "tooltip tooltip-" + $(this).attr('class');
        $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title');
        $('<p class="' + classTooltip + '"></p>')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    });
},

function () {
    // Hover out code
    $.each(toolTip, function () {
        $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText'));
    });
    $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function (e, event) {
    var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
    var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates

    var im1Height = $('#img1').height();
    var im1Width = $('#img1').width();
    var im2Height = $('#img2').height();
    var im2Width = $('#img2').width();

    if ($(this).hasClass('masterTooltip')) {
        var ratioHeight1 = e.pageY / im1Height;
        var propHeight2 = ratioHeight1 * im2Height;
        var mousey2a = propHeight2 + im1Height;

        var ratioWidth1 = e.pageX / im1Width;
        var propWidth2 = ratioWidth1 * im2Width;
        var mousex2a = propWidth2;

        $('.tooltip-masterTooltip')
            .css({
            top: mousey,
            left: mousex
        });
        $('.tooltip-masterTooltip1')
            .css({
            top: mousey2a,
            left: mousex2a
        });
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('masterTooltip1')) {
        var ratioHeight2 = (e.pageY - im1Height) / im2Height;
        var propHeight1 = ratioHeight2 * im1Height;
        var mousey2b = e.pageY - (im1Height - propHeight1);

        var ratioWidth2 = e.pageX / im2Width;
        var propWidth1 = ratioWidth2 * im1Width;
        var mousex2b = propWidth1;

        $('.tooltip-masterTooltip')
            .css({
            top: mousey2b,
            left: mousex2b
        });
        $('.tooltip-masterTooltip1')
            .css({
            top: mousey,
            left: mousex
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: this is the real deal.=D Good job @Vond Ritz

Answer (score 0):

Store your tooltip element collection in a variable:

```
var $tooltips - $('.masterTooltip,.masterTooltip1').hover(function(){ ... });
```

Then modify slighty to work against the collection instead of `$(this)`:

```
$(document).ready(
   function() {
      // Tooltip only Text
      var $tooltips = $('.masterTooltip,.masterTooltip1')
                          .hover(
                              function(){
                                  // Hover over code
                                  var html = "<div class='tooltip'>";
                                  $tooltips.each(function() { 
                                     var title = $(this).attr('title');
                                     $(this).data('tipText', title).removeAttr('title') 
                                     html += '<p class="tooltip-inner">' + title + '</p>';
                                  });
                                  html += "</div>";
                                  $(html)
                                     .appendTo('body')
                                     .fadeIn('slow');
                              }, 
                              function() {
                                  // Hover out code
                                  $tooltips.each(function() { 
                                      $(this).attr('title', $(this).data('tipText')) 
                                  });
                                  $('.tooltip').remove();
                              })
                         .mousemove(
                              function(e) {
                                  var mousex = e.pageX + 20; //Get X coordinates
                                  var mousey = e.pageY + 10; //Get Y coordinates
                                  $('.tooltip')
                                      .css({ top: mousey, left: mousex })
                               });
});
```

CSS

```
.tooltip {
display:none;
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
font-size:12px Arial;
}
.tooltip-inner {
border:1px solid #333;
background-color:#161616;
border-radius:5px;
padding:10px; 
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want two simultaneous tooltips when hovering over an image. This code will do that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Tooltip only Text
    'use strict';
    $('.masterTooltip, .masterTooltip1').hover(function () {
        // Hover over code
        var self = $(this),
            title = self.data('tipText') || self.attr('title'),
            altTitle = self.data('altTipText') || self.attr('altTitle'),
            tip = $('<p />').addClass('tooltip');
        self.data({
            "tipText": title,
            "altTipText": altTitle
        }).removeAttr('title').removeAttr('altTitle');
        tip.clone()
            .addClass('primary')
            .text(title)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
        tip.clone()
            .addClass('alternate')
            .text(altTitle)
            .appendTo('body')
            .fadeIn('slow');
    }, function () {
        // Hover out code
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function (e) {
        var titleX = e.pageX + 20, //Get X coordinates
            titleY = e.pageY + 10, //Get Y coordinates
            altX = e.pageX + 20, //Get X coordinates
            altY = e.pageY - 70; //Get Y coordinates
        $('.tooltip.primary').css({
            "top": titleY,
            "left": titleX
        });
        $('.tooltip.alternate').css({
            "top": altY,
            "left": altX
        });
    });
});
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LUFuY/

Comment: Almost...http://jsfiddle.net/LUFuY/1/

I added an image to the fiddle. Is there a way to make each separate title appear at the same time?

Comment: Do you mean one title per image?

Comment: Yes - one title per image and the title near the respective image